why my laptop changed typing of 集资?
it concerns typing Chinese by pinyin -> my keyboard always used to type 集资 (a fund) by pinyin "jizi". Now, because of some unknow for me reasons, when I want to write the same "fund" and type "jizi" on my screen appears 集資 - as you see, the character "capital" now is different = appears 資 instead of 资.
Why that might happen ? And most importantly, how can I come back to my previous "capital" character 资 ?
Your advise would be tremendously appreciated.
Thank you in advance !!

Looks like you've just changed the input to Traditional. Setting it back to Simplified should do the trick.

This is a good question for those who have just started to learn Chinese. Even for a native Chinese speaker, dealing with the computer settings on simplified Chinese characters and traditional Chinese characters can be confusing occasionally.

Use the combination of CTRL+SHIFT+F to quickly switch between traditional and simplified Chinese input.

这应该是与键盘输入法或系统的显示语言有关，当前可能是繁体中文，你需要把键盘输入法或系统的显示语言设置为简体中文
第一步：
打开Windows系统的设置

第二步：

第三步：

第三步中选择中文简体。
